# Linux cron job remove .zip files from folder every 12 hours

Tags: linux, cron

I'm looking for help to make a cron job that every 12 hours will delete all .zip files from a subfolder in my hostgator hosting account.

http://prntscr.com/7rr22d

After some google research I tried this command but nothing seems to happen

```
find /home/username/domain.com -type f -name "*.zip" |xargs rm
```

What should I put in the "Command:" field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
find /home/username/domain.com -name "*.zip" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```